# python, beautifulsoup, genius lyrics, how to remove references

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-3.7

Hello i'll explain you the problem

i have this wonderful code that grab from a genius page, the lyrics of a song.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://genius.com/Luis-sal-ciao-mi-chiamo-luis-lyrics'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

text = soup.select_one('div[class^="Lyrics__Container"], .lyrics').get_text(strip=True, separator='\n')
print(text)
```

now i'm using as example the url of [this](https://youtu.be/eIPyw84l27c) song, and the lyrics link is the link you can see in the code.
The output of this, is good without any problem, except for this part.

in the website is like this

[image: cose]
in the output is like this

```
Eee
(Ma chi ti caga)
Eee Ciao
(Ma chi vuoi che ti guardi)
```

as you can see, it goes to the next line and here is not a big problem, no one cares, but in some song like [this](https://genius.com/Avicii-the-nights-lyrics)
in the website for some reason it looks like this

[image: no]

in the output looks like this:

```
He said, one day you'll leave this world behind
S
o live a life you will rememb
er
My father told me when I was just a child
```

not very good.

That "reference" that how's it called, in html is contained inside the text, as a tag, and you can't delete it, because, every time you refresh or you load the page, the name of that class, for some reason, changes. Does anyone have an idea on how to fix that? It wuold be appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: do you have an example code we could work with?

Comment: Genius has an API have you tried getting the lyrics that way? https://docs.genius.com/

Comment: @Ira H the code is on the previous question

Comment: This question should be self-contained in that all the info to understand the problem and replicate it should be here.

Comment: ok, i'll edit the question with all the info you need.